# How much android native knowledge required to be flutter developer?

Tags: android, flutter, native

I am about to start flutter, I don't know android native and some people says basics of android native is required before starting flutter if yes then please guide me topics that I should
learn before starting flutter.

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working with Flutter for the past 2 years. In my opinion I think it is one of the fastest framework to pick up as a starter.

The best point to start is [the official doc/ tutorial](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install) from Flutter team. It covers the installation, step by step to create a `Hello World!` app and the Codelabs that show you Flutter in action.

It'd then be a good time for you to get your hand dirty with Flutter yourself. [Flutter Apparentice](https://docs.flutter.dev/apprentice-giveaway) is a great book/ tutorial that is recommended and supported to be free till Jan 6th, 2022 by Flutter team so pick that up quickly.

Going through the book, get a good grasp of the framework's core features (how it renders, the widget/UI system, file I/O, state management and the process of building an app from scratch till release), after a couple of apps you'll be well on your way to be a Flutter developer.

Some app suggestions are a simple app (countdown timer), some little more complicated apps (to do list with Firebase, news app with API), and then 1 or 2 advance apps (movies/ music app). Come to StackOverflow as always to find the support to your difficulties during the progress.

Welcome to Flutter and wish you all luck on your new journey!

Comment: Thanks for your guidance i would like to ask a 1 more question do i have to lern android native before startiing flutter?

Comment: No you don't need to. Flutter is made so you can skip the native work for each Android or iOS native platform. The `Dart` language and `Flutter` is enough for you to create lots of production-ready apps such as Google Pay app, etc. Check out the [sample apps](https://flutter.dev/showcase)!